# Not getting any data in my django template

Tags: django

I have a URL that calls my Create View with a primary key.  For some reason the html template never gets any data.  Have tied printing out pk, table.pk etc.  but no data seems to make it to the view...
my view looks like this:

```
class SegmentAddView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
  model = Program
  template_name = 'segment_add_view.html'
  form_class = SegmentForm
  context_object_name = 'program_info'
```

The models are as follows:

```
class Program(models.Model):
    air_date             = models.DateField(default="0000-00-00")
    air_time             = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
    service              = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    block_time           = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
    block_time_delta     = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
    running_time         = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
    running_time_delta   = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
    remaining_time       = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
    remaining_time_delta = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
    title                = models.CharField(max_length=190)
    locked_flag          = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deleted_flag         = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    library              = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=190,blank=True)
    mc                   = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    producer             = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    editor               = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    remarks              = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    audit_time           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    audit_user           = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=32)
        
class Segment(models.Model):     
    class Meta:
      ordering = ['sequence_number']
        
    program_id = models.ForeignKey(Program,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='segments',   # link to Program
    ) 
    sequence_number          = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=6,default="0.00")
    title                    = models.CharField(max_length=190, blank=True)
    bridge_flag              = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    seg_length_time          = models.TimeField()
    seg_length_time_delta    = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
    seg_run_time             = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
    seg_run_time_delta       = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
    seg_remaining_time       = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
    seg_remaining_time_delta = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
    author                   = models.CharField(max_length=64,null=True,default=None,blank=True)
    voice                    = models.CharField(max_length=64,null=True,default=None,blank=True)
    library                  = models.CharField(max_length=190)
    summary                  = models.TextField()
    audit_time               = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    audit_user               = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=32)
```

I have a button in my detail screen that does this:

```
   <button type="submit" value="add_segment" onclick="location.href='{% url 'segment_add' program.pk %}'">Add Segment</button>
```

The template looks like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  Segment Add
  {% if program_info %}
    <TABLE ID="pro-table" WIDTH="100%">
    <!--  <TABLE BORDER="0" TABLE_LAYOUT="fixed" WIDTH="100%"> -->
      <TR BGCOLOR="#15C1B5">
        <TD ALIGN="Right">Program Title:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">{{ program_info.title|truncatechars:30 }}</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Right">Library:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ program_info.library }}</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Right">Service Bureau:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ program_info.service }}</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="#15C1B5">
        <TD ALIGN="Right">Program Id:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ program_info.pk }}</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Right">Air Date:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ program_info.air_date|date:"Y/m/d" }}</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Right">Air Time</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ program_info.air_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="#15C1B5">
        <TD ALIGN="Right">Producer:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ program_info.producer }}</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Right">Editor:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ program_info.editor }}</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Right">MC:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ program_info.mc }}</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="#15C1B5">
        <TD BGCOLOR="#99CCFF" ALIGN="Right">Duration:</TD>
            <TD BGCOLOR="#99CCFF" ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ program_info.block_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="Right">Rem. Time:</TD>
            <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ program_info.remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="#CC99CC" ALIGN="Right">Run Time:</TD>
            <TD BGCOLOR="#CC99CC" ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ program_info.running_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="#15C1B5">
        <TD ALIGN="Right">Remarks:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left" COLSPAN="5"><PRE>{{ program_info.remarks|truncatechars:180 }}</TD>
        </PRE></TD>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>
    {% if program_info.segments.all %}
      <TABLE BORDER="0" TABLE_LAYOUT="fixed" WIDTH="100%">
        <TR BGCOLOR="#B0B0FF">
          <TD ALIGN="Center">&nbsp;#</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Center">Segment Title</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Center">Summary</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Center">Library</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Center">Author</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Center">Voice</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Center">Segment time</TD>
          <TD BGCOLOR="#CC99CC" ALIGN="Center">Run time</TD>
          <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="Center">Rem. time</TD>
        </TR>
        {% for segments in program_info.segments.all %}
          <tr BGCOLOR="#B0B0FF">
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top" WIDTH="35">{{ segments.sequence_number }}</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ segments.title|default_if_none:'No Title'  }}</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top"><PRE>{{ segments.summary|truncatechars:40 }}</PRE></TD>
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ segments.library }}</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ segments.author }}</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ segments.voice }}</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="CENTER" VALIGN="Top" WIDTH="10">{{ segments.seg_length_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
            <TD BGCOLOR="#CC99CC" ALIGN="CENTER" VALIGN="Top" WIDTH="10">{{ segments.seg_run_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
            <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="CENTER" VALIGN="Top" WIDTH="10">{{ segments.seg_remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
          </TR>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <form method="post" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}
        <TR BGCOLOR="#B0B0FF">
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top" WIDTH="35">{{ form.sequence_number }}</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ form.title }}</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top"><PRE>{{ form.summary }}</PRE></TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ form.library }}</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ form.author }}</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ form.voice }}</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="CENTER" VALIGN="Top" WIDTH="10">{{ form.seg_length_time }}</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <td><input type="submit" Value="Update"></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
      </TABLE>
      {% if form.errors %}
        <!-- Error messaging -->
        <div id="errors">
          <div class="inner">
            <p>There were some errors in the information you entered. Please correct the following:</p>
            <ul>
 {% for field in form %}
                {% if field.errors %}
                  {%  if field.label == "Seg length time" %}
                    <li>Segment Time:
                  {% else %}
                    <li>{{ field.label }}:
                  {% endif %}
                  {{ field.errors|striptags }}</li>
                  <br>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
 {% endif %}
{% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a> |
  <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
{% endif %}
```

The URL looks right when I check it, but there isn't any data in the HTML at all. Didn't think I would need to add context or anything because I am passing the primary key already for Program...

Any help would be great. Thought this would be a simple form. Display the program stuff, and then put up the segment form...

Comment: Why would a `CreateView` for a `Segment` automatically add a `Program` instance into the context...?

Comment: Because it's model is Program Model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's builtin generic views deal with only **one model** at a time. If one wants to deal with multiple things at the same time they would need to create their own views or extend the builtin ones. So a `CreateView` will only create instances of models and not display them like `DetailView` does. Your attempt also doesn't make sense due to the reason that a `CreateView` if not provided a `form_class` would generate one automatically using the `model` attribute.

Then how does one add more data to the context? Well one can override `get_context_data` to add more variables to the context and to set the foreign key to the created instance without having it in the form you can override `form_valid` method:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class SegmentAddView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Program # Remove this line, it is not useful
    model = Segment
    template_name = 'segment_add_view.html'
    form_class = SegmentForm
    context_object_name = 'program_info'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['program_info'] = get_object_or_404(Program, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        program = get_object_or_404(Program, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form.instance.program_id = program
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

> **Note**: `program_id` is a bad name for a foreign key as Django automatically appends `_id` to the field name to add an attribute
> which can be used to set or access only the related id. Also the
> column name in the database is also made this way, so you end up with
> `program_id_id` as a name.

Comment: Thank, I changed this to something much like what you have here.  The problem I have now is how to get the ForeignKey of my program_id into the segment instance form directly (I dont want it entered or displayed on the form).

Comment: @ToddB that's a different question, but check my edit anyway...